# How to transfer data from one phone to another (UDP protocol) using mobile data network

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I have developed an application which sends a message using UDP protocol from one phone to another, **in the same LAN** using the phones' *internal IP addresses* and Wifi.

However, if I want to achieve the same functionality by using mobile data (Edge, GPRS, 3G) etc, I cannot make the thing work just by using **external IP addresses** instead of internal IP addresses.

I have used UDP merely because I am just starting out with learning networking related app development.

Do I have to make use of a *specific* set of APIs for data transfer using 3G or 2G? How can I understand this scenario?

Comment: If you know the external IP of the device, then technically there should be no reason you cannot send from one device to the other, unless there is some firewall blocking.  I would guess this would be the case for data transmissions over the cell system, as the cell companies would get lots of complaints from users if they allowed DoS attacks and the like.  I would suggest looking into setting up a server in the middle so that each device speaks to the central server, which routes the packets accordingly.

Comment: Would this central server be another mobile phone?

Comment: A phone is not a server.  A server would be a computer, preferably on the internet, that receives requests from one or more clients, which in this case would be your phones.